# In C#, how to add data padding?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, padding

Sometimes you need to pad data (stream of bytes) to discrete block sizes.  For example, ProtectedMemory can only operate on blocks of data in multiples of 16 bytes.  I know some other classes such as ProtectedData and AESCryptoServiceProvider and AESManaged have built-in support for padding, but for those classes that don't have it built-in ... How do you pad data for ProtectedMemory?

Sure I can write it myself, adhering to standards such as ANSIX923 or ISO10126 or PKCS7, but there *must* be a good way to make .Net do it.  I would have expected that functionality to be part of Stream, or MemoryStream...  I just can't find it anywhere except in specialized encryption classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ProtectedMemory to store a 16 or 32 byte encryption key and then use AESManaged or AESCryptoServiceProvider to protect & store your data with padding.  Or use ProtectedMemory to store 16 or 32 byte optionalEntropy, and then use ProtectedData to protect & store your data with padding.

Comment: is not going to work on any device not running windows, you can also just write blocks of data and add 0 for padding and default to Zero for padding if you get a CryptographicException with a padding message